# How do I call a before_save method from a parent model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, inheritance, model, relation

I have two models :

```
class Game
  before_save :update_teacher
    teacher
  end

  def update_teacher
    teacher.update_attribute("something", true)
  end
end

class Puzzle < Game
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

I have many types of games. When any game is complete, I'd like to update_teacher.

But as you can see, Game does not belong to anyone. It's just where I keep all my global methods for all the games. I would never need to query `Teacher.games`. Instead, I only need to query `Teacher.puzzles`, or `Teacher.riddles` and so on.

It is because of this, that when I come to the `before_save` method, and I try to call `teacher`, it will fail because `teacher` is not associated with `game`.

So how can I keep my global Game class handling this method and still refer to its child's association?

*Also..*

I just realized that this before_save might not actually ever be called because it's not the Game model that's updating ( or is it? ). If it isn't..same question, how do I globalize this inherited method properly?

**Alternatively..**

I will admit that there might be an architectural flaw to how I'm going about my association. Would anyone recommend that I create *two* associations, or even just *one* association from `Game` directly with a `game_type`. Not sure what would be better or worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every game has a teacher, the `belongs_to :teacher` should be in the `Game` class and not in the subclass.

When you add a `before_save` in the `Game` and save a `Puzzle` it will call the `before_save` from the `Game` because `Puzzle` is a game, but `Game` has no knowlege of `:teacher`.

Please update your question with a more detailed description of what you want to accomplish and not of the circumstances.

**UPDATE**

What you can do, is have a method that is called on the parent class and is overridden by the child classes

```
class A
  before_save :do_x

  def do_x
    raise "Please implement this!"
  end
end

class B < A
   def do_x
     # do what B has to do
   end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. You're saying that both of them should be related to Teacher. But that gives me red signals when thinking of DRY practices. Maybe I should use a `has_many through: 'games'` relationship for `Puzzles`?

Comment: @Trip I don't think I can say anything for sure without understanding how the architecture of your game/teacher/puzzle is. That's why I asked for an update on the question to include that :)

Comment: @Trip updated the answer with another method you might want to use, too. But I cannot give you a better answer without knowing what are the relations between the games/puzzles/teachers

Comment: That's fine. You definitely answered all my thoughts here. Thanks so much Draiken!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `Game` is a good candidate for a [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) based `Module` that's included in your game classes:

```
# app/models/concerns/game.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module Game
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :teacher
    before_save :update_teacher
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def update_teacher
      teacher.update_attribute("something", true)
    end
  end
end

# app/models/puzzle.rb
class Puzzle
  include Game
end
```

This way `belong_to` and `before_save` are sent to `Puzzle` when `Game` is included.